# Jumpy exported animation

Tags: graphics3d, export, animation

When I make an animation of `Plot3D` using `ListAnimate` it looks decent.  But when I export the same frames with `Export`, the z-axis tick labels jump back and forth.  Here's a minimal example:

```
f = Table[
  Plot3D[(1 + Sin[2 \[Pi] t]) E^(-(x - Sin[2 \[Pi] t])^2 - (y - Cos[2 \[Pi] t])^2),
    {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotLabel -> t, PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> {-2, -2, 1}]
, {t, 0, 0.95, 0.05}];

ListAnimate[f]
(* looks OK *)

Export["f.gif", f, "AnimationRepetitions" -> \[Infinity]]
(* looks bad *)
```

[image]

Any idea how I can get `Export` to behave like `ListAnimate`?

Comment: Try a fixed PlotRange, like {{-2,2},{-2,2},{0,2}} instead of All

Comment: @flinty But what if one just needs `PlotRange->All`?

Comment: Just to expand on @flinty 's comment:  Without having a fixed z-axis each frame has a different z-range so the jumpiness should be expected.  One would either need a whole lot more frames to have a smooth transition or have a common z-axis.  The `ListAnimate` looks just as jumpy to me.

Comment: @JimB The weird thing is the changing height of the z-axis doesn't cause `ListAnimate` the same problem where the ticks switch back and forth from the left to right side.  Luckily @TimLaska's answer fixes the problem.

Comment: @ChrisK But just using `PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 2}}` gives the desired result with `ListAnimate` and `Export` (*Mathematica* 12.0, Windows 10).

Comment: @JimB My real problem has a fairly dynamic range of `z`, so I can't fix its range without losing a lot of the interesting detail.

Comment: It might be that several things reduce the jumpiness.  Just adding in `SphericalRegion->True` reduces the jumpiness in `ListAnimate`.  So does adding `ImagePadding -> 30` (by itself without `SphericalRegion`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try adding `ImagePadding` and `AxesEdge` to prevent the axes from jumping around.

```
f = Table[
   Plot3D[(1 + 
       Sin[2 π t]) E^(-(x - Sin[2 π t])^2 - (y - 
           Cos[2 π t])^2), {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotLabel -> t,
     PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> {-2, -2, 1}, 
    ImagePadding -> {{40, 0}, {0, 0}}, 
    AxesEdge -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {t, 0, 0.95, 0.05}];

ListAnimate[f]

Export["f.gif", f, "AnimationRepetitions" -> ∞]
```

[image]

Comment: Seems that `ImagePadding` isn't necessary?

Comment: @xzczd Maybe.  I saw some vibrations with the box when I commented it out on my windows machine (`12.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)`).  I also saw some clipping of the z-axis.

Comment: Perfect, this fixed both my minimal example and my real problem.  Thanks!

Comment: This solution does not visualize the height changes. Just number at the z-axis is dancing, but this is bad way. I guess the fixed `PlotRange` at highest value will give the best.